# PHP: isset () not working (false negatives)

Tags: php, validation, isset

Okay, I know that there are a few of these questions already on SO; but they don't actually solve my problem.

For this (cut-down) html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>test</title></head><body>
        <form method="post" autocomplete="on" action="application6.php">
            <p>
                <input  type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" maxlength="50" size="30">
                <label for="fullname">*Full Name</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input  type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="50" size="30">
            </p>
            <p>
                <select name="hours" id="hours">
                    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">*Hours</option>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have the following code

```
$error_array = array(
    " "
);

echo ("debug: ");
print_r($_POST);



$variables = array(
    'fullname',
    'email',
    'hours'
);

foreach ($variables as $variable_name) {

    if (isset($_POST[$variable_name])) {
        echo 'Variable: ' . $variable_name . ' is not set<br/>';
        array_push($error_array, " " . $variable_name);
    }


}
```

This results, in the submission of a blank form, in the output of

> debug: Array ( [fullname] => [email] => )

An alternative is to check if these elements are empty(), but empty() will return false positives for when "hours" is set to 0.

Why are these elements incorrectly registering as being set, and what means can successfully test inputs of different types?

Comment: `trim` is your friend, or `!= ''`

Comment: trim wont unset the variable, you should use empty() instead, which checks for null, false, 0, and ''  - these are always set, ie always present in the $_POST array ( unlike checkboxes ) they are just empty - I see your concern about empty you can also simply check for '' if you like as in != '', if you do look for empty string then trim is your friend : )

Comment: Try array_key_exists

Comment: @cmorrissey already tried trim() - will try (!='') !

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I would use empty, but as mentioned, there are cases where "0" will be a valid input

Comment: @Duncan - trim removes whitespace from front and back of strings - if you really must use isset then you need to use array_filter which will also remove 0's

Comment: You are checking if the variable **is set**, and in case positive you print a message saying its not. Invert your logic.

Comment: @Havenard - isset on input  type="text" will always be true

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix No it will not always be true, it will only "always be true" IF and ONLY if this specific form is used to submit to this specific script. Its possible for someone to access the script directly, and not even use method POST.

Comment: @Duncan - also you might want to close that <form> tag?  Just a thought.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix simply a casualty of having to cut several hundred lines of html/ php for the sake of brevity for the question :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your logic, you check if $_POST[whatever] isset, and if so, you then output "Variable is NOT set" this is the opposite of what you're if statement checks. Try adding a ! in front of isset:

```
if (!isset($_POST[$variable_name])) {
    echo 'Variable: ' . $variable_name . ' is not set<br/>';
    array_push($error_array, " " . $variable_name);
}
```

Comment: Although I was a complete idiot for not spotting this; also required || ($_POST[$variable_name]=="") to catch all true positives

Comment: the op's output is wrong the logic is correct, read this part of the question "Why are these elements incorrectly registering as being set"  the OP wondering whey they are set and is checking if they are set.  the text output should read "is set"

Comment: Do people really read the questions? or is it all a joke I wonder.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix  The message says "X is not set" if and only if it IS indeed set. PS. its possible for it not to be set, if the script is accessed outside of the form its supposed to come from (AKA always code defensively, as the OP is trying to do)

Comment: @Derokorian - the question is clearly why are they set, which they are - flipping the logic doesnt unset them.  Granted they are not set in the case of the form not being submitted but that is not the question.  'This results, in the submission of a blank form, in the output of'  AND 'Why are these elements incorrectly registering as being set'

Comment: ergo, when you submit a blank form text fields will always be set.

Comment: "isset () not working (false negatives)" its falsely negative because the logic is backwards. Checking if its an empty string is a different type of validation than checking if it was provided.

Comment: That is true, but the OP wanted to know why the elements where in the array, being placed there by first checking if they were set.  If they were not set the intent would be that they were not in the array, which with your answer is backwards.  As I stated the OP wanted to know why they were in the isset array not the not isset array.

Comment: I think the key here is that no single method will ever be able to validate all fields in a form. hours does not need the same validation as email for example, the former should probably just be isset && is_numeric while the latter should likely be !empty && filter_var(FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)

Answer (score 0):

try making sure the trimmed value is not an empty string and that the variable exists

```
foreach ($variables as $variable_name) {

    if (isset($_POST[$variable_name]) && "" != trim($_POST[$variable_name]) ) {
        echo 'Variable: ' . $variable_name . ' is not set<br/>';
        array_push($error_array, " " . $variable_name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST[$variable_name])) {
    echo 'Variable: ' . $variable_name . ' is set!!<br/>';
} elseif(!isset($_POST[$variable_name])){
    array_push($error_array, " " . $variable_name);
} elseif( empty($_POST[$variable_name])){
    echo 'Variable: ' . $variable_name . ' is empty!!<br/>';
} else{
   var_dump($_POST[$variable_name])
}
```

Comment: check all post variable before validatel, a function like: 
    public function trimArray($data){
        $arg = array();
        foreach($data as $k=>$v){
            $arg[$k] = trim($v);
        }
        return $arg;
    }
    public function stripTagsArray($data){
        $arg = array();
        foreach($data as $k=>$v){
            $arg[$k] = strip_tags($v);
        }
        return $arg;
    }

    public function praparePost($data){
        $prapare1 = $this->trimArray($data);
        $prapare2 = $this->stripTagsArray($prapare1);
         return $prepare2;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is no need to check if isset because it will always be set you only need to check for this

```
if( trim($_POST['key']) != '' ){

}
```

Also if you really need to use the isset

```
$post = array_filter( array_map('trim', $_POST), function($a){
      return $a != '';
});
```

That will remove them from $post